# Create a PDF with customer/order information for virtual product

Tags: magento2, pdf, virtual-products, dynamic

I've setup products as "Virtual Products" because I don't ship anything so thought this would be the best product type.

With that the option to attach downloadable PDF products. On sale of this product, I want to be able to allow for the customer to download several PDF attachments some of which will be generic and other will contain information dynamically populated.

This information will be things such as customer name, address as well as some of the product options such as turnover and employees. This will be populated within a PDF template for them to download as well as being available within the customers account area where they can view the order and re-download these PDFs.

Is this possible to do? If so does anyone have any pointers as to where I could start with this kind of product?

**Please note:** I'm new to Magento and I am eager to learn, all advice is much appreciated.